# Calling a method within my class states "incompatible types" even though it isn't?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, constructor

I have no idea why my class method will not accept the matrix as an input despite it being an `int[][]`.

Here's my main:

```
public class Lab1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matrix One = new Matrix(3, 3);
        Matrix.viewMatrix(One);
    }
}

/**
 * Here's my class called "Matrix":
 **/
public class Matrix {
    private int rows;
    private int columns;

    Matrix() {}

    Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        int[][] matrix = new int[rows][columns];
    } // matrix constructor

    public void viewMatrix(int[][] a) {

    } // viewMatrix
} // class
```

Comment: Your `viewMatrix` has an int[][] as Parameter not on object of type `Matrix`

Comment: Stop apologizing. Instead, explain your thought process. Your method expects an `int [][]` and you're passing it a `Matrix`. Why do you think those are the same?

Comment: Don't be discouraged from asking more question.

Answer (score 2):

The `viewMatrix(int[][] a)` signature doesn't allow the `Matrix.viewMatrix(One)`  call because a `Matrix` is not a `int[][]`.

I'd recommend you to change the signature to `viewMatrix()` and print a `matrix` instance field inside (like `Arrays.deepToString(matrix)`). The problem is that a `matrix` is not an instance field in your case. Make it so:

```
private int[][] matrix;
Matrix (int rows, int columns) { matrix = new int[rows][columns]; }
```

Also, you needn't keep `rows` and `columns` as fields. You will get them by `matrix.length` and `matrix[0]==null ? 0 : matrix[0].length` calls.

---

`int[]` and `Matrix` are reference types. It doesn't matter whether the `Matrix` class contains an `int` array, it isn't and won't be an `int[]` anyway.

---

There is another problem here - the line `Matrix.viewMatrix(...);`. The method isn't static, therefore you can't invoke it by the class name. But you are free to perform it like `One.viewMatrix(...)` (by JCC, it is better to name the variable like `one` or `firstMatrix`).

Comment: Deleted my answer as your is so much better.

Answer (score 2):

viewMatrix() is not static, so it should be called using a object, in your case its `One`, and `int[][]` is not same as `Matrix`.

I am assuming you want to do something with `One`'s matrix array, then you can simply call `One.viewMatrix()` and access its `matrix` variable `this.matrix` inside the viewMatrix()

```
        public class Lab1 {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Matrix One = new Matrix(3, 3);
                // One is a instance of Matrix class
                // So it should be
                One.viewMatrix();  
            }
        }
/** 
Here's my class called "Matrix":
**/   
        public class Matrix {
            private int rows;
            private int columns;
            private int[][] matrix; <= you need this

            Matrix() { 
            }

            Matrix (int rows, int columns) {
                this.rows = rows;
                this.columns = columns; 
                this.matrix = new int[rows][columns];
            } // matrix constructor

            public void viewMatrix() {
               // viewMatrix can access array using this.matrix

            } // viewMatrix
        } // class
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

```
Matrix One = new Matrix(3, 3);
```

you are creating a new object of type Matrix.  Therefore, when you make the next call,

```
Matrix.viewMatrix(One);
```

you are passing it a Matrix object, which is not an int[][] array, like it was expecting.

I think your confusion may be that you are creating an int[][] in the Matrix constructor.

Answer (score -1):

The viewMatrix method accepts 2-Dimentional array on int type and you are trying to send Matrix object and this two are not compatible.What you can do is

```
public class Matrix {
        private int rows;
        private int columns;
        private int[][] matrix;
        Matrix() { }

        Matrix (int rows, int columns) {
            this.rows = rows;
            this.columns = columns; 
            matrix = new int[rows][columns];
        } // matrix constructor

        public void viewMatrix(int[][] a) {

        } // viewMatrix
    } // class


public class Lab1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Matrix One = new Matrix(3, 3);

            One.viewMatrix(One.getMartix());  
        }
    }
```

Comment: (not a downvoter) Matrix.viewMatrix() seems to be invalid in your code

Comment: it was just for understanding purpose.Corrected